Woocommerce ajax checkout get wc_checkout_params is not defined
I have make custom option fileds for local pickup and is working before but after i have update all my plugins i ger the error
input
<input type="checkbox" class="input-checkbox" name="custom_shipping_option" id="pickup" value="pickup">

Send ajax data fuction
$('input[name="custom_shipping_option"]').change( function () {
            var checked = 0;
            if ( $(this).val() == 'pickup' ){
                checked = 1;                
            }
            
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: wc_checkout_params.ajax_url,
                data: {
                    'action': 'woo_get_ajax_data',
                    'custom_shipping_option': checked,
                },
                success: function (result) {
                    $('body').trigger('update_checkout');
                    console.log(result); 
                },
                error: function(error){
                    console.log(error); 
                }
            });
        });

Get ajax data
add_action( 'wp_ajax_woo_get_ajax_data', 'woo_get_ajax_data' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_woo_get_ajax_data', 'woo_get_ajax_data' );
function woo_get_ajax_data() {
    if ( $_POST['custom_shipping_option'] == '1' ){
        WC()->session->set('custom_shipping_option', '1' );
    } else {
        WC()->session->set('custom_shipping_option', '0' );
    }
    echo json_encode( WC()->session->get('custom_shipping_option' ) );
    die(); // Alway at the end (to avoid server error 500)
}

refreshing session shipping methods data
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_review', 'refresh_shipping_methods', 10, 1 );
function refresh_shipping_methods( $post_data ){
    $bool = true;
    if ( WC()->session->get('custom_shipping_option' ) == '1' ) {
        $bool = false;
    }
    // Mandatory to make it work with shipping methods
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_shipping_packages() as $package_key => $package ){
        WC()->session->set( 'shipping_for_package_' . $package_key, $bool );
    }
    WC()->cart->calculate_shipping();
}

On above get the error in my console it say "ReferenceError: wc_checkout_params is not defined"
